# fstab mount problem

Tags: mount, fstab

Fresh install Of Mint 17.

I have few partition and 3 OSs Win/Ubuntu-Gnome/ and this newly installed Mint. One of these partition is a storage disk for all documents, photos etc.. and I used to use it from both Linux OSs without any problem and mount it during start by editing `fstab`. Last days i decided to try Mint 17.3 and after installation I wanted to edit `fstab` via disk manager and

- after changing mounting properties to

  ```
  dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxx(here proper UUID) /mnt/Local ext4 nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
  ```

  it failed with

  ```
  Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sda3:
  Command-line mount "/mnt/Local"' exited with non-zero exit status 32:
  mount: wrong fstype, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda3`
  ```
- So I check it with `fsck.ext4 /dev/sda3` : no faults
- Then I tried mount with `mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/Local` And it was mounted
  successfully :) (and it is mounted as ext4 - as it should be)

I tried all possible options via `UUID`, via `/dev/sda3` via LABEL and it is not working - the same error... I have to add that the same option in fstab under my Ubuntu Gnome works properly... Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try mounting with "defaults" instead of "nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show" ?

Comment: yes, i tried, with the same result...

Comment: when you mount manually, mount | grep sda3 - what's the output? can you try using those exact options in your fstab?

Comment: It looks like something is wrong with x-gvfs-show.. (other options works fine). Don't know why as it used to work always (i used it in many distros) Thanks for all comments guys! i will try to investigate what's wrong with gvfs-show.

Answer (score 1):

First Method:

1. using the following command to check filesystem type and UUID and partition associated

   ```
   # sudo blkid
   ```
2. in /etc/fstab add the entry in following format as

   ```
   UUID=XXX.XXX.XXX /mnt/local   ext4    defaults        0 0
   ```

   (in-case file system is ext4)
3. mount the partition using

   ```
   # mount -a
   ```
4. to check partion is working fine or not using

   ```
   # df -h
   ```

Another method:

1. use following command to check the partition(current and umounted)

   ```
   # lsblk
   ```
2. enter the entry in /etc/fstab eg: if block partition is /dev/sda6

   ```
   /dev/sda6 /mnt/local ext4 defaults 0 0
   ```

Any one method will help you...

Comment: As i wrote above - it is a problem with x-gvfs-show. Not a matter of fs_spec or fs type (checked with all possible and relevant) or if a partition is working (it is).

Comment: I will get back on this soon

Comment: I was going through google and found one link, kindly check with this method by adding comment=x-gvfs-show                                                           http://askubuntu.com/questions/454225/fails-to-auto-mount-device-error-mounting-system-managed-deviceubuntu-14-04

Comment: Yes, found the same... i have to check why it worked on other distros.. (perhaps it was not working and just ignoring this param) Thanks!

Comment: Looks like it was discussed few times - http://askubuntu.com/questions/594197/unrecognized-mount-option-x-gvfs-show-or-missing-value

Answer (score 0):

From your question it seems you wrote `/dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx /mnt/Local ext4 nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0` in your `/etc/fstab` when it should be `UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx /mnt/Local ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,exec,auto,nouser,async,nofail,comment=x-gvfs-show 0 0`.

(`defaults`: `rw suid dev exec auto nouser async`)

Comment: Thanks, but you can address it by few things :) I checked them all and it was not a matter here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with wrong option "x-gvfs-show". "comment=x-gvfs-show" shall be used instead. 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/594197/unrecognized-mount-option-x-gvfs-show-or-missing-value